# react and socket.io. problem when deleting message listener. with component unmounting

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, socket.io

I'm creating a simple application on socket io + react, node js, mysql, typescript. When I go to the chat room, I have an entry registration. When exiting, the exit is logged. Everything seems to work fine, but when you re-enter the room (or another room) and send a message to the server, multiple messages are sent. And it depends entirely on how many times I entered or left the room. That is, I clicked into the room 1 time, 1 message is sent, I left the room and went into it (or another room), there are already two messages sent to the server, etc.
I originally thought that the state was saved on the server and the room was not exited, but my tests showed that this was not the case. Everything happens as it should. But listeners remain in place.

My code client:

```
export const Room = () => {

const {id} = useParams();

const socket = useContext(SocketContext);

useEffect(() => {

const sendNewMessage = (msg: string) => {

console.log(msg);

}

if(socket){

socket.emit('join', id);

socket.on('new_message_in_room', sendNewMessage);

}

return () => {

if(socket){

socket.removeAllListeners('new_message_in_room');
socket.emit('leave', id);

}

};

},[socket]);

const newMessage = () => {

socket && socket.emit('room_message', {id, msg:"message"},)

}

return <div onClick={newMessage}>room {id}</div>

}
```

my code server:

```
const room = (room, socket, io) => {

socket.join(room);

console.log('leave', socket.rooms, 'count', io.engine.clientsCount);

socket.on('room_message', (data) => {
console.log('1')
io.to(data.id).emit('new_message_in_room', data.msg);

});

}

module.exports = room;
```

leave

```
socket.on('leave', (room) =>{

socket.leave(room);
console.log('leave', socket.rooms, 'count', this.io.engine.clientsCount)

});
```

Firt room  enter and send message

[image]

Exit and entering several times and sending message

[image]

This photo shows what user is one

[image]

i created a wrapper for this:

```
    export const SocketConnection = () => {

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const [socket, setSocket] = useState<Socket>();

const jwt = useSelector((store:ReduxStore) => store.jwt.user.jwt);

useEffect(() => {

const socket = io("http://localhost:4000",{auth: {jwt: jwt}, transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false});

setSocket(socket);

socket.emit('allData_room');

socket.on('allData_room', (msg) => dispatch(newRoomData(msg)));

socket.on('update_room', () => socket.emit('data_room'));
socket.on('update_message', () => socket.emit('data_message'));

socket.on('new_message', (msg) => console.log(msg));
socket.on('delete_room', (msg) => console.log(msg));
socket.on('delete_message', (msg) => console.log(msg));

return () => {

socket.close();

};

},[jwt, setSocket]);

return <SocketContext.Provider value={socket as Socket}>
<Outlet/>
</SocketContext.Provider>

}
```

source:

https://github.com/Cthulhu-tech/chat/blob/main/client/src/components/socket/socket.tsx

Comment: What happens if you change useEffect dependency from `socket` to empty `[]`

Comment: Nothing changes

Comment: What's in your SocketContext? How do you create the socket connection to server?

Comment: I added to the post. I honestly don't even know what's wrong